# Chaining records?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my raw data, I can see my patient sent SMS messages to his doctor.

```
messageid|PhoneNbr|Patient|Created|Status
asd134|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-26 20:34:10.728000|Outbound
ffg5|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-26 20:35:29.177000|Inbound
xv33|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-26 20:35:37.294000|Outbound
dd234|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 17:12:02.593000|Outbound
dfg234|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 17:14:20.010000|Inbound
nu6|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 17:14:31.977000|Outbound
rx3|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 19:33:06.487000|Outbound
zxc4|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 20:24:09.833000|Inbound
yt123|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 20:24:10.033000|Outbound
ac21|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 20:24:47.454000|Outbound
```

To track when a message gets a response I need to keep track of the status changes
(outbound->inbound->outbound->inbound...), removing any rows where the status does not change, producing the following output

```
messageid|PhoneNbr|Patient|Created|Status
asd134|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-26 20:34:10.728000|Outbound
ffg5|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-26 20:35:29.177000|Inbound
xv33|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-26 20:35:37.294000|Outbound
dfg234|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 17:14:20.010000|Inbound
nu6|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 17:14:31.977000|Outbound
zxc4|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 20:24:09.833000|Inbound
yt123|555-1212|Joe Smith|2020-08-27 20:24:10.033000|Outbound
```

My query is not "chaining" my statuses. It simply repeats the raw data

```
SELECT 
a.messageid,
a.PhoneNbr,
a.Patient,
a.Created,
a.Status
FROM message AS a LEFT JOIN message AS b on a.messageid = b.messageid
```

How can I produce the output I want?

Comment: All of your message IDs are unique.  How are the messages related?  Your join will only cause each record to join to itself, and your query will only return your original data set.

Comment: You're right. Messages are unique. the Message IDs are system-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PostgreSQL LAG() function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) to determine the "previous" status, and then select only those rows where there has been a status change:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.messageid,
        a.PhoneNbr,
        a.Patient,
        a.Created,
        a.Status,
        LAG(a.Status, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Patient ORDER BY Created) AS PrevStatus
    FROM message
) subquery
WHERE subquery.Status <> subquery.PrevStatus
OR subquery.PrevStatus IS NULL
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. Answer accepted but I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up (Sorry).

Comment: No worries, happy to help